# Amount of sunlight and its effect on the eye sight

Tags: eye, sunlight, light

Are there any studies or commonly understood consensus on how the amount of light and type (different types of artificial vs. sunlight) of light that an individual is daily exposed to affects their eyesight?

Studies would be better in this case, as I would like to see to what degree a young relative's (she is a teenager) deteriorating eyesight could be improved by her getting more sunlight or better natural light. In this case my intention is to use the studies to encourage a behavior that could help her.

Comment: Welcome Dee. What have you found so far in your search for the answer? That's part of how asking questions on SE works, demonstrating what you've found by searching yourself and then asking for assistance with what you are unable to find/understand.  Where did you find the fundamental premise that any kind of light can heal or prevent poor vision?  Is this just an assumption you made or is it based on something?

Comment: Welcome to Health, Dee! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Adding to the previous comment:  You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!